# TextWrangler: How to do a Find then Replace: How to Specify what text to find and what text to replace

Tags: text-editor

I'm stuck what most would think is one of the basics of editing with TextWrangler - how to do a find/replace!

In Notepad++ on Windows, the Replace is, to me, very straight forward: you select it from the menu and a pop up windows appears with a 'find what' field and a 'Replace with' field. You enter in those what you need to find and replace, respectively. And it does the job.

Not so on TextWrangler on the Mac: Sure, there's a replace option under the 'Search' menu. But that's it - no guideance or prompting as to what to do. No pop up prompt or anything.

I'm sure it works and perhaps I need to relearn for the ways of TextWrangler, but a Google Search and a look the TextWrangler manual gave me no clues. So I came here :) Please advise me, it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Search` menu select `Find...` it will show the Find & Replace box.

You can use also `Command + F`

Latest TextWrangler version is 4.5

Comment: +1 Accepted :) That does the job though my thoughts are that TextWrangler does not make this as obvious as NotePad++ does as it buries the Replace functionality under find and still having a separate Replace option too. But thank you @Guido Preite

Comment: @Guido, How to keep the replacement to the text which you've selected only?